# Regex error in Typescript not matching dot

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am using this regex to validate input field for allowing only one dot and numbers.
it works perfectly fine with javascript. But when using it with typescript it only accepts numbers and gives null for dot(.) when matching.

here is my regexobject:

```
RegExp = new RegExp(/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/g)
```

And this is how i am using it.

```
@HostListener('keydown', [ '$event' ])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
        return;
    }
    let current: string = this.changeRate.nativeElement.value;
    let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    console.log(next+" : "+String(next).match(this.regex)+" : " +event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special to TypeScript here (after all TypeScript is just JavaScript with type annotations). Citing from the MDN: [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

> There are 2 ways to create a RegExp object: **a literal notation and a
>   constructor**. To indicate strings, the parameters to the literal
>   notation do not use quotation marks while the parameters to the
>   constructor function do use quotation marks.

The following three expressions create the same regular expression:

```
/ab+c/i;
new RegExp('ab+c', 'i');
new RegExp(/ab+c/, 'i');
```

And:

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules
>   (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are
>   necessary. For example, the following are equivalent:

```
var re = /\w+/;
var re = new RegExp('\\w+');
```

However, your actual problem is, it looks like you use the Regex class name as the variable name. Otherwise, your regex definition is fine.

```js
var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/g);
const str = `1.1`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Same issue, it also matches for number only. i also checked for any other functionality that might have caused this problem. but this is the only event associated with the input box.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is wrong: `RegExp = new RegExp(/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/g)`

You'd either write

- `this.regex = /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/g`

or

- `this.regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*$", "g")` (using `\\.` within the string to properly output `\.`)

I'm assuming typescript is doing something behind the scenes to try to parse it in the second way, and it's escaping the `.` instead of literally writing `\.`

Comment: i did console.log for regex object, so when i use \\. it prints 
/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/g  and with \. it printed this
/^[0-9]*.?[0-9]*$/g  but in both the cases it won't accept a dot, also I tried both of the syntax. (i previously declared it a private variable.)